# Why it is not possible to increment and then pass the value in set method by ++

Tags: java, operators, int, setter, operation

I have a line of code that works like this,

```
mrq.setId((mrq.getId()+1));
```

But, When I tried to write it like this,

```
mrq.setId((mrq.getId()++));
```

It doesn't work, The error is, `Invalid argument ot the operation ++/--`

What is the technical reason behind it?

Comment: Uh, because "mrq.getId()" isn't a primitive that you can assign to?  You can't say "mrq.getId() = 1", either ;)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536223/why-doesnt-integer-parseint1-work-in-java

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651615/in-java-why-cant-i-write-i-or-i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The increment operator requires a field or variable.  Evaluating `getId()` doesn't result in an id field; it returns a copy of the value `getId()` returns (by "copy" I mean a literal copy for primitive types and a new reference for reference types).  `getId()` might be implemented as `return id;` internally, but you don't get back the field `id`, only a copy of its value.

The closest equivalent would be `int i = getId(); setId( getId() + 1 ); return i;`, but you're asking a lot to allow `getId()++` as syntactic sugar for such an expression.

Answer (score 3):

`x++` is essentially equivalent to `x = x + 1`, which doesn't make sense in your case:

```
mrq.getId() = mrq.getId() + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`++` operator is used to increment the value of variable by 1. so `a++` is treated as `a=a+1`. That means the operand on which it is used will be where the assignment will be done.

When you write `mrq.getId()++` it doesn't provide you an operand variable which it can increment and hence this doesn't work.