# Why cannot I increment returned value?

Tags: java, return-value, increment

I noticed a surprising behaviour.

I **can** write so:

```
Integer integer = 0;
integer++;
```

But I **cannot** write so:

```
getInteger()++;
```

Here's my `getInteger()` method:

```
public static Integer getInteger(){
    return 0;
}
```

For me, two snippets look the same.

But the second piece of code returns an error:

```
unexpected type
        getInteger()++;
                  ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
```

Why is the second construction forbidden?

Often, I feel forced to write "ugly" code like this:

```
obj.set(obj.get()+1);
```

It looks redundant.

Comment: you can not perform constant++ i.e. 5++. In your method you are return 0 ;

Comment: How different is obj.get()+1 from obj.get()++ ?

Comment: What would you expect it to do? Translate into a call to `setInteger(getInteger() + 1)`? Don't forget that the Java *language* doesn't know anything about getters and setters...

Comment: I don't think this question is useful, because it can't be asked by someone who actually understands what `++` means. If you ask yourself *"why is there a `++`, anyway, when `+1` is just as easy to write?"*, and can answer correctly, then you already know the problem with the code in this question. (But then, it's a duplicate of something that got a lot of upvotes, so...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't the post increment operator work on a method that returns an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291861/why-doesnt-the-post-increment-operator-work-on-a-method-that-returns-an-int)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`x++` is not the same as `x + 1`. It's short for `x += 1`, i.e. `x = x + 1`; increment, then assign. So `getInteger()++` means `getInteger() = getInteger() + 1`, which makes no sense. You're adding one to a value, not incrementing a variable.

Apart from that, `++` works on `int` but not `Integer`, but even if you were returning an `int` you couldn't increment it with `++`:

```
class Test {
    static public void main() {
        getint()++;
    }
    static int getint() {
        int a = 0;
        return a;
    }
}
```

gives

```
Test.java:3: error: unexpected type
        getint()++;
              ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
```

(In C++ you could make this work with references, but Java doesn't have those.)

Comment: @Alnitak Integer doesn't, but Java 5.0+ supports it with boxing.

Comment: @PeterLawrey fair point about boxing - presumably the compiler is unable to box in the `getInteger()++` scenario

Comment: `ETOOMANYLANGUAGESINMYHEAD`

Comment: The operator `++` is not defined for the type Integer

Comment: @Zhuinden that was my initial argument, but as Peter pointed out, with auto-boxing it's possible to use it.  The real problem is simply that the result of the function is a _value_ instead of an _lvalue_

Answer (score 2):

`8++` will not make sense, while

```
int x=8;
x++;
```

does make sense, because x++, is working like `x+=1`, i.e., `x=x+1`
and `8=8+1` is something not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

As it says, it requires a **variable** for `++` operator. `++` increments a value that is stored somewhere, so the incremented value is now stored in that location. Your function just returns a **value**, which is not a **variable**.

It's as simple as Rahul mentioned in the comment.

```
//This works
x=5;
x++; //Now x=6 since x++ is equivalent to x=x+1;

// This doesn't work
5++; // This doesn't even make sense, trying to do 5=5+1??

// Similarly, getNumber() is just a value that is returned, it is a value, not a variable
// So it is like the second case
// This doesn't work
getNumber()++; //Trying to do getNumber()=getNumber()+1; ??
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning an `int`; you're returning an `Integer` object.  The `Integer` class is immutable and has no `++` operator of its own.

Also, the `++` operator requires that its operand be an `lvalue`, i.e. an assignable variable as opposed to a `value`.  The result of `getInteger()` is the latter.

In the case of your first test:

```java
Integer integer = 0; integer++;
```

Java's autoboxing allows the use of the `++` operator, but only because Java automatically converts the `Integer` into an `int` and then back again, and because the variable `integer` is an `lvalue`.  It's more or less equivalent to:

```java
int tmp_int = integer.intValue();
int result = tmp_int++;
integer = Integer.getInteger(tmp_int);
(void)result;
```

`result` - the effective "value" of the expression isn't `integer` because you've used the "post increment" version of `++`, so the result is the value that `integer` had *before* it was incremented.

Comment: @PeterMortensen https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425376

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the second construction forbidden?

`Integer` is immutable, so you couldn't change it anyway.  `int` is mutable but since it only returns a *copy* on the value, this won't work either.

E.g.,

```
public static Integer getInteger(){
    return 0;
}

// what would this do
getInteger()++;

// now the method has been changed to 
public static Integer getInteger(){
    return 0+1;
}
// so now
System.out.println(getInteger()); // prints 1 ??
```

> obj.set(obj.get()+1);

This breaks encapsulation as well.  I would suggest a method like this:

```
AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
i.incrementAndGet();
```

Or you could have your own:

```
i.incr();
```